# Python 3.x session, class, and serialization

Tags: python-3.x, class, session, serialization

EDIT: I wonder if you think the issue might be that I'm trying to store an entire dictionary row returned from database in a session variable?

Here's the error (full error printout is at bottom of this post):

```
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

FYI: I'm not using JSON anywhere in my code.

Here's the relevant parts of my code (main.py):

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, t_id_user=None, t_email=None):
        self.t_id_user = t_id_user
        self.t_email = t_email

    def create_or_update(self, t_create_or_edit="Edit"):
        #How necessary are the "=None" below?
        #self.t_id_user = userCreate(self, t_id_user=None, t_email=None):
        #How necessary are the "=None" above?
        if t_create_or_edit == "Create":
            self.t_id_user = userCreate(
                self.t_email
                )
        else:
            self.t_id_user = userUpdate(
                self.t_id_user_edit,
                self.t_email
                )

    def get_from_id(self, t_id_user):
        # logic to retrieve your user's data from your database of choice
        myData = usersGet(
            t_id_user="0",
            t_email=""
            )
        self.t_id_user = myData["t_id_user"]
        self.t_email = myData["t_email"]
        return self

def userClearSession(t_which="user_current"):
    logging.debug("Start of userClearSession()")
    t_id_user = "0"
    t_email = ""
    user_instance = User(t_id_user, t_email)
    if t_which == "user_current":
        session["user_current"] = user_instance
    else:
        session["user_edit"] = user_instance
    return

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/userRegister', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(t_title="Login or Register", t_message=""):
    if "user_current" not in session:
        userClearSession(t_which="user_current")
    return render_template(
        "userRegister.html",
        t_message=t_message,
        t_js="userRegister.js",
        t_title=t_title
        )

def userCreate(t_which="current"):
    id_user = 0
    db_cursor = data_cursor()
    q = ""
    q += "INSERT INTO tbl_users "
    q += " ( "
    q += " i_security_level"
    q += ", t_email"
    q += " ) "
    q += " VALUES "
    q += " ( "
    q += " %(t_security_level)s"
    q += ", '%(t_email)s'"
    q += " ) "
    try:
        if t_which == "current":
            user_instance = session["user_current"]
        else:
            user_instance = session["user_edit"]
        vars = {
            't_security_level': int(session["user_instance"].t_security_level),
            't_email': AsIs(session["user_instance"].t_email)
            }
        db_cursor.execute(q,vars)
    except Exception as e:
        t_message = "Error"
    else:
        id_found = userIsInDB(session["user_instance"].t_email)
        if id_found >= 1:
            t_id_user = id_found
            if t_which == "current":
                session["user_current"].t_id_user = t_id_user
            else:
                session["user_edit"].t_id_user = t_id_user
        t_message = "User Created"
    db_cursor.close()
    db_conn.close()
```

The full error message:
I'm having a hard time getting any meaning out of this error message and need help. It doesn't appear to point to any parts of main.py, though I know the error is somewhere in there and I'm pretty sure I narrowed it down to the code you see above:

```
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1970, in finalize_request
response = self.process_response(response)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2269, in process_response
self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 378, in save_session
val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 166, in dumps
payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\url_safe.py", line 42, in dump_payload
json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 133, in dump_payload
return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\tag.py", line 305, in dumps
return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 211, in dumps
rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
return cls(
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 100, in default
return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
Open an interactive python shell in this frameraise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__}
```

Comment: What are the ```userCreate()``` and ```userUpdate()``` functions doing?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I added userCreate to original msg above.

Comment: Where are you using ```json``` in the code?

Comment: Nowhere. I wonder if you think the issue might be that I'm trying to store an entire dictionary row returned from database in a session variable?

Comment: Are you storing a ```User``` object somewhere? Or sending it as a parameter/payload where only JSON is permitted?

Comment: Yes. Notice the userClearSession function?